# Is it possible to show an alertDialog is still showing when starting a child activity?

Tags: android

Is it possible to show an alertDialog that is still showing when starting a child activity?

I am asynchronously fetching results from a server. The request is sent from activtiy A which then shows a progressDialog. When the first result is received, activity A starts activity B, which will receive the following results. But the progressDialog shown from A should still be shown when B starts.

How can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work but you could try changing the owner activity from Activity A to Activity B with: `Dialog.setOwnerActivity()`  for more info see [the dialog docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOwnerActivity%28android.app.Activity%29)

Comment: Thanks, tried it but I didn't get it working. I'l just show activty B at once instead.

Comment: Another option would be to let Activity B know when it starts if the Dialog for Activity A is already showing. If it is then you could immediately show the Dialog on Activity B.  Perhaps it would happen fast enough that the users wouldn't see the dialog getting destroyed and then recreated.

Comment: That's what i initially did, but it doesn't happen fast enough. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using an actual `Dialog` you might consider using an `Activity` with a dialog theme. To the user they appear the same but you as the developer have much more control of them.